# How to separate business logic if property is set to true in a way that the service would only log what CRUD operations will be executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement where I need to create a service with some business logic in it that will determine which resources should be deleted and which should be created in a database.
The content of the resources is read from a JSON which is statically defined in the project root. Here is an example:

```
{
  "subjects" : [
    {
      "name" : "New-subject",
      "description" : "Math subject",
      "price" : "100"
    },
    {
      "name" : "New-subject-2",
      "description" : "Chemistry subject",
      "price" : "120"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Already-Existing-Subject",
      "description" : "Physics subject",
      "price" : "120"
    }
  ]
}
```

Name is considered as a unique identifier, and after reading and mapping the JSON to my internal model, I need to determine which resources should be created, and accordingly create them, and which should be deleted i.e. are not defined in the JSON resources, but are present in the database.

Now the requirement has a sub-task where it says: "If the option readOnlyAndLog is enabled, the service should only go through the JSON resources, determine which actions should be performed, and log them without executing any create/delete operations in the database".

So with this option enabled, the output should be the following for example:

```
New-subject will be created 
New-subject2 will be created
Already-Existing-Subject is already defined in the DB
Subject3 will be deleted
Subject4 will be deleted
.....
```

My question now is how can I reuse the same service, but for these 2 different scenarios depending if the readOnlyAndLog is enabled or not? Whats the best practice for this kind of separation upon a service?

Comment: Where is `readOnlyAndLog`? Within the request? As a JVM parameter? In the application.properties file? Do you have access to the code that does the CRUD operations?

Comment: @JettoMartínez It should be placed in the applicaiton.properties file. No implementation yet, I was just looking for an idea or approach on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bean initialization depending on the property value.

You can create an interface `SubjectHandler` with the method
`void handleSubject(Subject subj)`.

Then define two implementation of this interface: `ReadOnlySubjectHandler` and `DatabaseSubjectHandler`. In the first one, implement the logic of checking subject & logging and in another one put a logic of checking subject & perform CRUD operation in database.

Then you can use Spring annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "readOnlyAndLog", havingValue = "true/false")` and place it upon your implementation of interface.

Next time you start an application Spring will create only one instance of `SubjectHandler` depending on what value `readOnlyAndLog` has.

Comment: To add on what you've described, shouldn't be even better in order to avoid duplication, to separate and extract the logic of checking JSON and then use it in the ReadOnlySubjectHandler and DatabaseSubjectHandler ?

Comment: Sure, the part of reading json shouldn't be included in described method and it wasn't expected. As you can see, the method `handleSubject ` accept only one java object, deserialized from JSON earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your project, here is a possible solution.

First, defining entity `Subject` with name being the unique identifier:

```
public class Subject {
    @Id private String name;
    @Column private String description;
    @Column private BigDecimal price;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Subject)) {
            return false;
        }
        Subject subject = (Subject) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, subject.name);
    }
}
```

Define `app.read-only-and-log` in `application.properties`:

```
app.read-only-and-log=false
```

and using `@Value` to bind the value to `SubjectServImpl`:

```
@Value("${app.read-only-and-log}")
private Boolean readOnlyAndLog;
```

writing business logic in `SubjectServImpl`:

```
public void update(List<Subject> incoming) {
    List<Subject> existing = subjectRepo.findAll();

    // cross check incoming and existing
    for (Subject i : incoming) {
      if (existing.remove(i)) {
        if (readOnlyAndLog)
          log.info(i.getName() + " is already defined in the DB");
      } else {
        if (readOnlyAndLog)
          log.info(i.getName() + " will be created");
        else
          subjectRepo.save(i);
      }
    }

    if (readOnlyAndLog)
      existing.forEach(e -> log.info(e.getName() + " will be deleted"));
    else
      subjectRepo.deleteAll(existing);
}
```

You can try calling `subjectServ.update(subjects)` from your `SubjectController`, while changing the value of `app.read-only-and-log` in `application.properties` would switch the behavior of the service.

**One side note on the business logic:**
looping through all existing rows in `SubjectRepo` at every call for update may not be a desired practice when your project grows larger in size.

Hope I can be of a little help.